# How to deal with friend requests in social API REST

Tags: rest, api, api-design

I'm designing an API that a social network app will consume. I need to manage friend requests between users.

I have this endpoint:

```
POST /users/{userId}/friend-requests 

{ requesterId: string }
```

that is called when `requesterId` wants to be a friend of `userId`. It returns a `FriendRequest`:

```
{
    id: string,
    requesterId: string,
    requesteeId: string,
    status: [PENDING, ACCEPTED, REJECTED],
    createdOn: date
}
```

When `userId` log in, it will fetch pending friend requests using endpoint below:

```
GET /users/{userId}/friend-requests?status=PENDING
```

that will return a `FriendRequest` array. So, that endpoint return incomming friend requests, i.e. those requests where `userId` is the requestee.

How should I design the endpoint to fetch the outgoing friend requests? Should it be somethig like this?

```
GET /users/{userId}/friend-requests/incoming
GET /users/{userId}/friend-requests/outgoing
```

Is that a good approach?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that approach.

Comment: I use similar endpoints (nothing to do with social networks) at work. No one has jumped off the roof yet. :)

Comment: if you want to keep the look of your incoming requests(namely GET /users/{userId}/friend-requests?status=PENDING) you could use GET /users/{userId}/friend-requests?status=AWAITING as well

Comment: While admittedly I know nothing about your model, I would use a nested 'event': `{action:[ACCEPTED, REJECTED], timestamp:"yyyy-mm-dd 12:30pm utc"}` instead of an enum in the request status. pending would be a null value.

Answer (score 1):

The approach seems fine. However, to give a complete answer, here is what I would also consider.

Maybe make the ‘direction’ of the friend request a filter, so you can say

```
?direction=incoming
```

or, closer to an implementation:

```
?requestee_id=your_id
```

Comment: That was just my thought: From a ressource perspective, there is no difference between befriending-requests. `incoming` and `outgoing` are no "material" difference, only a different attribute.